# mapreduce job not running

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run mapreduce but able to run getting below error

```
16/04/28 13:17:07 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/04/28 13:17:07 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/04/28 13:17:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:09 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:10 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:11 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:12 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/04/28 13:17:14 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Please Note I have checked the question no 20620949 and toster.ru/q/57046#answer_208326 and many other relevant after verifying above Ifound yarn is not installed in my local machine,so please let me know is yarn is required to run MR job in single machine I mean in my local linux box (no cluster nothing) , can we run MR jobs without yarn?

Answer (score 0):

with hadoop-2 it YARN is the default scheduler, which manages resource/containers.
So it is mandatory to have YARN. You may start YARN services on single host, it doesn't require any cluster.

Comment: thanks Neeraj but I can not see "start-yarn.sh" file in my installed location even though I searched in all location, thats the main problem,thats why I asked is yarn required or not

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't need to install YARN. In that case you'll need to install hadoop-mapreduce-v1. But MRv1 is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. My guess is that you already have YARN installed but you just haven't started the service.

One of the other things you can do is to get an out-of-the-box image from one of the Hadoop distribution vendors: Cloudera or Hortonworks.

Answer (score 0):

its solved now,I am using chef for deployment and there I could not find "start-yarn.sh" but we made all as service,when I started the service "hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager" it start working,
any way thanks for your suggestion and comments.